# How to scrape player stats from futbin.com for multiple players using BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my last question I got a great answer on how to scrape fifa player stats from futbin.com.
The problem I found was that the answer was specific for 1 player and I could not apply and modify that code for example multiple players.

What I'm looking for is how to apply the code below to scrape stats from multiple players and save them in a dataframe.

The code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = {}
for s in soup.select(".left_stat_name"):
    data[s.get_text(strip=True)] = s.find_next(class_="stat_val").get_text(
        strip=True
    )

print(pd.DataFrame([data]).T)
```

Is there a simple way to scrape the stats for the following players and save them into a dataframe?

The players I would like to use in this example:

```
urls = ["https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi", 'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/529/kylian-mbappe', 'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/542/cristiano-ronaldo']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a `for loop` and append to your `data`.

Here's how:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi",
    'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/529/kylian-mbappe',
    'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/542/cristiano-ronaldo',
]

data = []
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    data.append(
        {
            s.get_text(strip=True): s.find_next(class_="stat_val").get_text(strip=True)
            for s in soup.select(".left_stat_name")
        }
    )
custom_index = [u.rsplit("/")[-1].replace("-", " ").title() for u in urls]
print(pd.DataFrame(data, index=custom_index).T)
```

Output:

```
                 Lionel Messi Kylian Mbappe Cristiano Ronaldo
Pace                       85            96                89
Acceleration               91            96                87
Sprint Speed               80            96                91
Shooting                   92            86                93
Positioning                93            91                95
Finishing                  95            91                95
Shot Power                 86            86                94
Long Shots                 94            79                93
Volleys                    88            83                86
Penalties                  75            70                84
Passing                    91            78                81
Vision                     95            80                82
Crossing                   85            78                84
FK. Accuracy               94            63                76
Short Passing              91            83                82
Long Passing               91            70                77
Curve                      93            79                81
Dribbling                  96            92                88
Agility                    91            92                87
Balance                    95            82                71
Reactions                  94            92                95
Ball Control               96            90                92
Composure                  96            84                95
Defending                  38            39                35
Interceptions              40            38                29
Heading Accuracy           70            73                90
Def. Awareness             32            34                28
Standing Tackle            35            34                32
Sliding Tackle             24            32                24
Physicality                65            76                77
Jumping                    68            77                95
Stamina                    72            86                84
Strength                   69            76                78
Aggression                 44            62                63
```